# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/core/TSFBuilder

Tags: dropwizard, objectmapper, jackson-databind

I'm using maven and dropwizard, getting `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/core/TSFBuilder` error when I initiate an Object Mapper.

Tried to override the dependency by adding `com.fasterxml.jackson.core` version 2.10.0 to POM (also tried a few other versions), but still getting the same error.

Any suggestion?

Comment: make sure you have jackson.core version 2.10.0.pr2

Comment: @venkat I added `2.10.0.pr2` to POM but still not working

Comment: @roe - FYI, you can accept your own answer (on this page) as well.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Resolved. Check out below:

- Use `jackson.core` version higher than 2.10.x
- Whether your code also uses `org.codehaus.jackson` and it causes dependency conflicts